# Implementing a synchronous method with calling the <asyncmethod>.Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, httpclient

I have this async method:

```
public async Task<RES> PostAsync<RES>(string url, string content) where RES : new()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var readAsStringAsync = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return await readAsStringAsync.FromJsonAsync<RES>(mySerializerSettings);
    }
}
```

Where `FromJsonAsync` is implemented as an extension method:

```
public async static Task<T> FromJsonAsync<T>(this string data, JsonSerializerSettings settings) where T : new()
{
    return (T)(await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<T>(data, settings));
}
```

Now I want to add a regular synchronous `Post` method and I thought the implementation would be:

```
public RES Post<RES>(string url, string content) where RES : new()
{
    return PostAsync<RES>(url, content).Result;
}
```

But this **doesn't** really work. I see that the request is sent via a Http sniffer and I get a response back, but I get stuck when debugging and can't continue.

BTW, this **does** work (with `Result` instead of `await`):

```
public RES Post<RES>(string url, string content) where RES : new()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        var readAsStringAsync = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return readAsStringAsync.FromJson<RES>(mySerializerSettings);
    }
}
```

Where `FromJson` is implemented as an extension method:

```
public static T FromJson<T>(this string data, JsonSerializerSettings settings) where T : new()
{
    return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data, settings);
}
```

The application is a web backend (WebApi).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which kind of application is this?

Comment: @i3arnon - A web application backend (WebApi).

Comment: I find it odd that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync` is what deadlocks. It's simply a `Factory.StartNew` wrapper over `DeserializeObject`, which is obsolete BTW.

Comment: Some relevant info [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx).

Comment: @AmirPopovich sorry, I meant `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - DeserializeObjectAsync doesn't cause the problem. I've changed my implementation to use the synchronous method and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Because you're blocking on async methods. Don't do that.

Comment: @i3arnon - ConfigureAwait(false) didn't help as well. I'll try adding it to all of the async calls.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Ok. I thought about preventing code duplication but maybe this isn't the best thing to do.

Comment: You can't. You're better off with a completely synchronous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a deadlock on your hands.

Asp.net uses a `SynchronizationContext` to post continuations back to the request context. If the context is blocked (like it is in your case on `PostAsync<RES>(url, content).Result`) then the continuation can't be executed and so the async method can't complete and you have a deadlock.

You can avoid it by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
public async Task<RES> PostAsync<RES>(string url, string content) where RES : new()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        var readAsStringAsync = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await readAsStringAsync.FromJsonAsync<RES>(mySerializerSettings).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

But it's better to just **avoid blocking synchronously on async code to begin with and having two different versions for sync and async.**

Comment: Ok - This did work. Adding ConfigureAwait(false) to all the async calls prevented the deadlocks. After reading some comments here I think that I'll duplicate my code for the synchronous operation using synchronous calls only. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AmirPopovich Consider having only the async version without any synchronous overloads. It isn't always possible but that's the direction many are taking.

Answer (score 2):

Although possible, I wouldn't use the answer provided by @i3arnon. Generally, you shouldn't block on async code. Although `ConfigureAwait(false)` does work, it can lead to confusion in your code-base where other developers may also end up blocking using `.Result`, without using `ConfigureAwait` or understanding the implications of that.

Instead, expose synchronous methods which are *really* synchronous:

```
public RES Post<RES>(string url, string content) where RES : new()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        var result = client.UploadString(url, content);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RES>(result, jsonSerializerSettings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I'll go with the synchronous way it will probably be using web client.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a non-async function and you want to start a task that will call PostAsync and wait for this task to finish and return the result of the Task. Is this your problem?

- To start a Task, use Task.Run( () => ...);
- To wait for the Task use Task.Wait(...);
- To see if the task stopped because of an exception: Task.IsFaulted
- The result of the task is in Task.Result

Your code could be:

```
public async Task<RES> PostAsync<RES>(string url, string content) where RES : new()
{
    // start the task that will call PostAsync:
    var postTask = Task.Run( () => PostAsync(url, content));
    // while this task is running you can do other things
    // once you need the result: wait for the task to finish:
    postTask.Wait();
    // If needed check Task.IsFaulted / Task.IsCanceled etc. to check for errors

    // the returned value is in Task.Result:
    return postTask.Result;
}
```

Comment: This is not my problem. You just wrapped the async call with a Task. Thanks for the answer anyway.